# How do I move data from one table into another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following query which pulls 1000 rows of data:

```
select barcode, type from collections where user = 'myusername'
```

I need to move this data to my new `collectors_collections` table. The `user` column is now labeled `username`.

What is the quickest way to do this? A query of some kind or some other way? I am using the latest MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try running this query:

```
INSERT INTO
    collectors_collections(barcode, type, username)
SELECT
    barcode,
    type,
    `user`
FROM
    collections
WHERE
    `user` = 'myusername';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simplistic approach which I would use it to just cut and paste the results of your selection into a text editor.  And perform some simple search/replaces to create insert statements for your new table.  Then just paste the new insert statements into your mysql client.

I assume you are not wanting this functionality with a running program.